# Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, into-outfile

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hitnrunf_db");

$result=mysql_query("select * from jos_users INTO OUTFILE 'users.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""' TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ");

header("Content-type:  text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_desired_name.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

in the above code  in query string i.e string in side mysql_quey

we are getting following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\wamp\www\samples\mysql_excel\exel_outfile.php on line 8
```

in query string '\n' charter is not identifying as string thats why above error getting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the double quote as: `\"` instead of `""`

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from jos_users INTO OUTFILE 'users.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ");
```

An un-escaped `"` will prematurely terminate the string.

Example:

This is incorrect: `"A " is a double quote"` 
This is correct: `"A \" is a double quote"`