# mySQL Load Data INFILE - T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_String Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

`LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE`picklist`FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

but when I execute it, this error displays:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\wamp\www\dX\csvImport-picklist.php on line 20`

What is wrong with my SQL query?

Comment: not psychic, you will have to show us csvImport-picklist.php

Comment: Already a down vote without even a comment? I am asking a question, am I not? Why the down vote?

Comment: your question as written is unanswerable, do you ask your doctor to fix your broken arm but not let him see the arm?

Comment: Downvote for two reasons: 1) This is a VERY common error so a quick search would reveal it. 2) You need the surrounding code to help pinpoint. Without that, we're guessing and it'll probably get closed as "possible duplicate" or "too localized" unless there's more info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719350/syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have an unescaped " (in the enclosed by) but impossible to say without seeing more.

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE `picklist` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";  // Added the escape character (slash) before the double quotes
```

Comment: surely this is a comment not an answer

Comment: Yes - but if I put code in, then I add as an answer as the code gets screwed up in comments, especialy with those quotes. Question will probably be deleted anyway in about 2 minutes ;)