# session management in php

Tags: php, mysql, session, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719350/syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-in-php)

Hello I am trying to design a web page in php to implement session and concept like login and logout.Below is my basic code.

```
<?php    
session_start();    
$host = "localhost";    
$username = "USERNAME";    
$password = "PASSWORD";    
$db = "test";    
@mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("error");    
@mysql_select_db($db) or die("error");    
?>
```

I am getting an error as unexpected_T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 3.Please help to remove this error.Is it anything wrong with SOL injection ?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719350/syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-in-php

Comment: have you tried using a framework?  you shouldn't write your own login code; the security risk is too great

Comment: You should also use `mysqli` functions instead of the old deprecated `mysql`.

Comment: You probably aren't `escaping` your strings properly..

Comment: should I use escape sequence?

Comment: @prakash_d22: No, you should use prepared statements, for example with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should stop using `MYSQL` extension as it is going to be deprecated soon. Instead you should be looking into other alternatives which are rich and safer such as `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL`.

Check [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

As found in above page:

> ```
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
> ```
>
> used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> ```
>     mysqli_real_escape_string()
>     PDO::quote()
> ```